# WebUsb: How to fix "NetworkError: Unable to claim interface."

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps, webusb

I am trying to use an android tablet connect using WebUSB. It finds my thermal usb printer and is able to open an connection. However at the time of device.claimInterface(0) I always get a error 'NetworkError: Unable to claim interface'

I tried restarting the android tablet, made sure no other applications were using the device, I restarted the device. I made sure no printers were setup through android. I tried running device.reset() before and I tried running device.releaseInterface() before. I tried finding other interfaces to connect with.

If you're gonna reply about running the manual command, I have to use this through a PWA for our customers. So its not a good solution to run manual commands on a android terminal to release the interface due to the linux driver loading by default, is there anyway around this?

```
navigator.usb.requestDevice({filters: []})
            .then(selectedDevice => {
                device = selectedDevice;

                return device.open();
            })

            .then(() => {
                this.log('Set configuration');

                return device.selectConfiguration(1);
            })
            .then(() => {
                this.log('Claim Interface');

                const interfaceNumber = device.configuration.interfaces[0].interfaceNumber;

                device.configuration.interfaces.forEach(interfaceA => {
                    this.log('interface: ' + interfaceA.interfaceNumber);
                });

                this.log('Interface Number:' + interfaceNumber);

                return device.claimInterface(interfaceNumber);
            })
            .then(() => this.print(device))
            .catch(error => {
                this.log(error);
            });
```

Comment: Hi Ray, I'm facing the same issue with my receipt printer. Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: No, sadly did not.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue, with a Numworks calculator this time. Did you find a solution yet?